# Typescript generic callback type hint with generic collection

Tags: typescript, generics, callback

I'd like to define a constructor of a generic class which takes a callback that takes a collection of one of the generic types. Although I can successfully define the callback type without a collection, I get an error with the collection. The error is "TS2371: A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation".

This gives me the error, but is the type definition I want:

```
import {List} from "immutable";
export class BackendToUI<BM, UM> { 
  constructor(private backendToUI: (BM, List<UM>) => UM) {}
}
```

This works, but isn't the type that I want:

```
export class BackendToUI<BM, UM> { 
  constructor(private backendToUI: (BM, UM) => UM) {}
}
```

I get the same issue with `UM[]` and `Array<UM>`, so the issue isn't due to some implementation problem in the immutable List type definition.

Defining the type in advance doesn't help either, though I didn't expect it to:

```
import {List} from "immutable";
type backendToUIType<BM, UM> = (BM, List<UM>) => UM;
export class BackendToUI<BM, UM> { 
  constructor(private backendToUI: backendToUIType<BM, UM>) {}
}
```

Anyone know how to declare this callback type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that parameter names in type positions in TypeScript are not optional. Everywhere you wrote a function type like this

```
(BM, UM) => UM
```

You need to be writing parameter names

```
(b: BM, u: UM) => UM
```

e.g. Here, instead of

```
constructor(private backendToUI: (BM, List<UM>) => UM) {}
```

You need

```
constructor(private backendToUI: (b: BM, u: List<UM>) => UM) {}
```

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why does Typescript compile the definition without the parameter names and collection? Specifically, why does this compile: `constructor(private backendToUI: (BM, UM) => UM) {}`?

Comment: ...answering my own question... it's because it's interpreting BM and UM as parameter names instead of types. D'oh!